# formating a string and pass it to an URL in python

Tags: python, django

How can i append two different strings variable in a url. 
But this is not accepting

```
def get_customer_action_by_target_group(self):
       payload = {"TargetGroupID": "%s" % self.TargetGroupID, 
       "Date":"%s" % self.date,
                }

    if not self.TargetGroupID or not self.date:
        get_target_group_id = int(raw_input("Please provide the target Group id:"))
        get_date = (raw_input("Please provide the date as required:"))
        self.TargetGroupID = get_target_group_id
        self.date = get_date
    response = self.send_request(self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url % self.TargetGroupID %
                                 self.date,
                                 json.dumps(payload),
                                 "GET")

    print response, response.text, response.reason

    return response
```

Comment: `get_customer_action_by_target_group_url` is the method itself, it doesn't make sense to try and treat it as a string.

Comment: No it not  the method .. it is just the variable itself, the url variable

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url % self.TargetGroupID % self.date
```

is incorrect; assuming `self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url` is a format string containing `%s` **exactly twice**, you should use a two-element tuple for the right-side argument to the `%` operator:

```
self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url % (self.TargetGroupID, self.date)
```

Comment: Cool. but i'm receiving it this -> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Well, **what** is the value of `self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url`?

Comment: get_customer_action_by_target_group_url = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup'

Comment: bascially this variable contains an URL. So self.get_customer_action_by_target_group_url . contains  get_customer_action_by_target_group_url = 'https://api4.optimove.net/current/customers/GetCustomerActionsByTargetGroup'

Comment: As I said earlier, this string must contain `%s` in places where you want to insert values of `self.TargetGroupID` and `self.date`…